# how to extract source table using sql?

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to write a query that extracts and transforms data from a table and then insert those data into target table and that whole table data should  be in single column in target table.below is the query i wrote

```
INSERT INTO Table2(column1) VALUES
    (SELECT * FROM Table1);
```

table 1

```
id  | ename  | email  |  country     |
1     d          ..        ..    
2     v          ..        ..      
3     s          ..        ..
4     n          ..        ..
```

in table2

```
src_data  |  src_column  |  src_tablename
1             eid
2             eid
3             eid
4             eid
d             ename
v             ename
s             ename
n             ename
email1        email     
email2        email
email3        email
email4        email
country1      country
country2      country
country3      country
country4      country
```

how can i achieve  this ...can you plz suggest me  to get this

Comment: It it is oracle SQL then You can use nested table concept. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm

Comment: Which database it is? Oracle , sqlserver, mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
INSERT INTO table2  
SELECT id, 'id', 'table1' FROM table1 
UNION SELECT ename, 'ename', 'table1' FROM table1 
UNION SELECT email, 'email', 'table1' FROM table1 
UNION SELECT country, 'country', 'table1' FROM table1
```

uses hardcoded names of the columns and the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot,and it is working fine. plz share the query with generic code also.

Comment: I have'n got generic code. As I said this works only for hardcoded names of the columns.

Comment: but i want to achieve this task through java when i use this i got an errors like (")is missing ...even when i put  that..what i did is   string query=("  INSERT INTO table2  
SELECT id, 'id', 'table1' FROM table1 
UNION SELECT ename, 'ename', 'table1' FROM table1 
UNION SELECT email, 'email', 'table1' FROM table1 
UNION SELECT country, 'country', 'table1' FROM table1");       ..how can i rectify this problem?

Comment: In your first comment you said it works fine. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: ok let me explain that in first i tried that query in mysql work bench, its working.but when i tried that through java it is giving errors like what i explained in above comment.

Comment: So this is not sql error. It is Java code error. You must post all the relevant code in order to understand where the problem is including the connection. So either you edit your question if it is not that much of code and explain where you think there might be a problem or make another question.